# If automorphism group Aut($Z_n$) is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$, wouldn't it then have to be abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If automorphism group Aut($Z_n$) is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$, wouldn't it then have to be abelian? Because $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ is abelian, and isomorphism preserves "abelianism".

I am a bit confused here. I understand why it is isomorphic but I came upon this contradiction. I assume I am looking at this the wrong way.

Comment: Yes, $Aut(\mathbb{Z_n})$ is abelian. Why do you think it shouldn't be the case?

Comment: I got a bit confused because generally composition of functions is not comutative.

Comment: Yes, but for some functions that works. As you probably know matrices do also not commute in general, but those that have just diagonal entries do for example. In this case we have the $1$-dimensinal diagonal matrices whose entry is a unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is abelian. That is because every automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is just given by multiplying an invertible number (to make it bijective), i.e. a number whose representative in the integers is coprime to $n$. Therefore one can directly see that the automorphism group is abelian since the multiplication of numbers is commutative.